# How to recursively return the number of 'toy' items in the direct object and all of that object's direct children

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

There is a `Person` class and it contains the following:

- int toys
- List children
- SumToys()

`SumToys()` returns all of the 'toys' in the direct object (the one `SumToys` is being called on) and its direct children only (not children of children).

```
class Person
{
    private static int toys;
    private static List<Person> children = new List<Person>();

    //Constructor
    public Person(int toysInput, List<Person> childrenInput)
    {
        toysInput = toys;
        childrenInput = children;
    }

    //Returns its own toys and direct children but NOT children of children
    public static int SumToys(List<Person> children)
    {
        int toysTotal = toys;

        for(int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++)
        {
            toysTotal += children[i].SumToys(); //I am trying to call SumToys but it says to 'qualify it as a type name instead

        }

        return toysTotal;
    }
}
```

Here is a sketch of what the tree is supposed to look like:

[image: What the tree should look like]

So if I called `SumToys` on object 2 it should return 13.  If I call it on object 4 then it should return 4.

Comment: I don't see why the variables and the function are static. Also, this line `toysTotal += children[i].SumToys()` should probably be `toysTotal += children[i].toys` if you don't want the sum of toys of children of children.

Comment: And constructor assign given parameters, instead it should be `toys = toysInput`. And remove all `static` from the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all `static` keywords from members of the class. Values of static members are shared between different instances of class.

Fix constructor to update class members instead updating provided input arguments

Make `Toys` member public for reading and use it in total amount calculation.
When you call `SumToys` on children it will calculate total amount of toys for all descendants.

You don't need provide children as arguments to `SumToys`, because children already given in constructor.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Toys { get; };
    private List<Person> children;

    public Person(int toys, List<Person> childrens)
    {
        ToysInput = toysInput;
        children = childrenInput;
    }

    public int SumToys()
    {
        var total = toys;

        for(int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++)
        {
            toysTotal += children[i].Toys;
        }

        return total;
    }
}
```

Using of class will look like

```
var four = new Person(4, new List<Person());
var five = new Person(5, new List<Person());
var six = new Person(6, new List<Person());
var two = new Person(2, new List<Person { five, six });

four.SumToys() // return 4
two.SumToys() // return 13
```

As alternative for calculating sum of toys you can use LINQ

```
public int SumToys()
{
    return children.Aggregate(Toys, (total, child) => total += child.Toys);
}
```